Write a mysql index on a converted string
There's a query I need to support that I can in no way control (redshift federated query against aurora rds mysql)
select * from tbl 
where BINARY rtrim( CAST(col1 AS char)) = BINARY rtrim(CAST( 'searchterm' AS char))

col1 is a varchar(1024).  How can I write an index to cover this where clause?  I have an index on col1 but it's not using it.

There is no way that MySQL can use an index which covers the WHERE clause because the column appears inside a function.  A function index might be usable, but MySQL does not support them AFAIK.

One possible workaround: Store rtrim( CAST(col1 AS char)) as a separate bona fide column, in binary collation, then index that column.

@TimBiegeleisen https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/post/functional-indexes-in-mysql

Why do you use CAST? varchar column and string literal casting to char obviously makes no sense. Also RTRIM makes no sense too until the value contains trailing spaces. And specify binary collation instead of explicit BINARY modifier. https://dbfiddle.uk/ADhvRphR

@Akina I do not use it, AMAZON uses it

Oh, you use CMS... if so then only virtual indexed generated column may be a solution, I think - and then only if CMS supports this.
